# How to call interface method from multiple classes in c# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, interface

I am trying to make a chessgame in c# WPF. I have miltiple classes, one for every kind of chesspiece and they all implement the same interface. All pieces objects are stored in a 2d array of type object[,] (of which have a feeling it's not the right way). I want to loop through this array to draw every corresponding image by calling Board[x, y].ImgURI but i get:

CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'ImgURI' and no accessible extension method 'ImgURI' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

```
 class Rook : Igamepiece{...}
 class King : Igamepiece{...}
 class Queen : Igamepiece{...}

 interface Igamepiece{
     public string ImgURI { get; set; }     //property that holds the image Uri
 }
 class Main{
     public object[,] Board = new object[8, 8];         //array containing objects of different types

     for (int y = 0; y < Board.GetLength(0); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Board.GetLength(1); x++)
            {
                GameArea.Children.Add(new Image
                {
                    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Board[x, y].ImgURI, UriKind.Relative)),
                    Width = SquareSize,
                    Height = SquareSize,
                    Margin = new Thickness(nextX, nextY, 0, 0)
                });
                nextX += SquareSize;
            }
                nextX = 0;
                nextY += SquareSize;
        }
 }
```

Comment: When you create a collection of type object, there is a good chance you are doing something suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change:

```
public object[,] Board = new object[8, 8];
```

to:

```
public Igamepiece[,] Board = new Igamepiece[8, 8];
```